# My iPad won't text to phone numbers

Tags: ipad

my iPad Air 2 used to text to all apple products and now I can only text to iPods and iPads that use email. I looked at what everyone else did but it didn't help. I get the red error when ever I do try. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the iPad is having difficulty associating numbers with the Apple IDs associated with the people you're contacting. Back up everything via iCloud or by connecting to iTunes and then restore your iPad https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201252

Restore information from your iCloud and iTunes backup and make sure that iMessage is activated in the settings of your iPad and try to send your messages again.

If it's still not working then restore the iPad again but set it up brand new.

Answer (score -1):

your iphone need to be connected (see settings Messages/Messaging) on the phone to enable sending proper SMS.

If it is imessage you only want to send, then check if you have a phone number connected to your iMessage setup, that may be required.

Comment: Sorry I actually have an iPad Air 2, so there is no phone number

Comment: the phone number is set on the iphone, not the ipad. Or, maybe you do not have an iphone at all? The imessage setup just links the imessage to one or many emails and one or many mobile numbers.

Comment: To text other iPhones via iMessage, which I believe the OP is asking about, an iPhone is not necessary. I can text other iPhones from my Mac without an iPhone linked.

Answer (score -3):

Maybe you need a service in order to text phone numbers. Try viewing emails in contacts.